# Why is Excel VBA executing a command correctly if I run it in debug modus but not in "normal" modus?

Tags: excel, vba

It is about the command:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd /d" & "N:\Preise\Makros\Felix\Temp\" & "&& FtpComm4.bat"
```

Why is Excel VBA executing a command correctly if I run it in debug modus, but in "normal" modus it does nothing?

Comment: What do you mean correctly? Excel otherwise freezes/crashes and error pops up? If yes then what error etc.? Might be also good to share more code (before the line above)

Comment: If i run excel vba in debug modus he executes the command correctly if I just run it normal. It does not execute the command.

Comment: The code is about to start a windows shell to execute a ftp upload and the commands are saved in that .bat file

Comment: It would be better if you shared more code before this statement. The issue might be that you are skipping some rows that are throwing errors.

Comment: No the other rows are not throwing errors. If I execute the same .bat file directly in windows or in debug modus it runs normally without error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give excel a timeout to let the shell execute the command:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
```